# How Do I Edit NPM CLI Scripts In My Package.Json?

Tags: json, command-line-interface, aws-cdk

My current `script` uses the `cdk` and looks like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "cdk": "cdk"
  },
```

How would I change this script to run something before the cdk?

For example:

```
  "scripts": {
    "cdk": "npm run test && cdk"
  },
```

I've tried this and it skips over the tests.

My ideal situation, is to run the tests before deploying to the AWS CDK.

Answer (score 0):

scripts in /node_modules/.bin can be executed in scripts by name.

you combine execution of multiple scripts with &&.

You could create a the following scripts:

```
"scripts": {
  "cdk": "cdk", // executes /node_modules/.bin/cdk
  "test": "jest", // executes /node_modules/.bin/jest
  "test-and-build": "npm run test && npm run cdk"
}
```

or

```
"scripts": {
  "cdk": "npm run test && npm run execute-cdk",
  "test": "jest", // executes /node_modules/.bin/jest
  "execute-cdk": "cdk" // executes /node_modules/.bin/cdk
}
```